# Query to count number of columns in a Sql Server View

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2012

Like we had query to find no of columns in a Table, is there any similar query to find total no of columns in a Sql Server View ?

Answer (score 5):

Even simpler is to use sys.columns.

```
select count(*)
from sys.columns
where OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('YourView')
```

Comment: This is simpler indeed. The advantage of the other approaches is: They would work with any *ad-hoc* statement, joined sources etc. But the OP wasn't asking for this actually. So +1 from my side ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Larnu's comment, I tend to prefer the Table-Valued-Function

**Example**

```
Declare @tsql nvarchar(max) =  N'Select * from YourView_Table_Or_Query'

Select column_ordinal
      ,name
      ,system_type_name 
 From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql,null,null )
```

**-- Or for the Count**

```
Select ColumnCnt=count(*) 
 From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql,null,null)
```

Comment: Ah, yes! forgot about the TVF (introduced with v2012). +1 From my side

Comment: As did I. I should really begin using that; far easier than shoving everything in a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the rather clumsy procedure `sp_describe_first_reuslt_set` you can use the generic abilities of XML:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourView FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS XSINIL ,TYPE).value('count(/row/*)','int');
```

**Edit**: Forgot to add `ELEMENTS XSNIL` which would omit columns with a value of `NULL` otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

--this might help

```
SELECT v.name, count(1) ColumnCount
FROM SYS.VIEWS v
INNER JOIN SYS.all_columns c ON v.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE v.name IN (SELECT name FROM sys.VIEWS)
GROUP BY v.name
ORDER BY v.name
```

SELECT name
FROM sys.VIEWS, can be replaced by viewname/s or query which returns viewname/s

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).